# Can you deal esd damage to an internal PCIe solid state drive while it is inside an anti-static bag?

Tags: esd

I apologize for the paranoia, but my mind refuses to rest. I have recently been working on a laptop. While doing so, my SSD (internal, it's a PCIe board) was inside an anti-static bag (the very cheap kind, my idea of sealing it was folding one edge) and I was frequently gripping a light metal pan. The SSD was never removed from the bag, but as I was working, the frequent touching caused the metal pan to move across my work surface until I discovered that it was on top of the SSD which was inside the bag. Presumably, the metal pan will have rubbed against the outside of the bag at some point, over the part containing the SSD. Could this have damaged the component inside the bag?

Comment: Assuming it's a metalized bag, not if it's sealed. Faraday cage. That said, it won't survive the ultimate form of ESD: being struck by a lightning bolt. Rubbing a conductor on an insulator is a pretty bad way to generate ESD within the conductor to begin with isn't it? All the excess free charge in the conductor can easily leave the conductor because it's a conductor.

Comment: Even if it wasn't sealed, you are probably fine. Most SSD's are a plastic case around a very small circuit board (unless you are talking about the PCIe boards). It's difficult to damage unless you touch the contacts.

Comment: Also, why would contact with a metal pan cause any ESD, unless the pan had a high voltage on it? After sitting on the desk for a while, the pan should approach ground potential.

Comment: @RonBeyer it's a PCIe board. I'll update to reflect that.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Doesn't friction, caused by rubbing one object on another, generate static?

Comment: @J.Mini Friction causes electrons to transfer from one material to another and they must accumulate to be able to produce a shock. Free charge can't move easily once in an insulator, but they can in a conductor so it's difficult for a charge imbalance to accumulate in a conductor since it's much easier for it to equalize. Ever try to scoop water with a sieve?

Comment: @DKNguyen And what's the insulator here? Isn't the outside of an anti-static bag known for causing static damage?

Comment: @J.Mini The insulator would be the plastic bag. An metalized anti-static bag is a insulator film sandwiched between two conductive films. You could charge it up if you took the effort to and it would hold that charge as long as you didn't let it touch anything else for too long, but it acts as Faraday cage would never reach the inside of the bag. Maybe the situation you are talking about is the bag storing charge and shocking something else, not the stuff inside it. But that's also really unlikely. I have never heard "the outside of an anti-static bag known for causing static damage".

Comment: And if you are talking about a different type of antistatic bag, you need to say so.

Comment: @DKNguyen I'm referring to how it's generally advised not to put a component on top of an anti-static bag, which is probably your "shocking something else, not the stuff inside it" case.

Comment: @J.Mini That might be because if you put a component on a conductive surface and you shock anywhere on that surface, you are shocking the component too because conductor. On the other, hand if you put it on an insulative surface and it is holding a charge it could also shock the component.